# Translating an English menu

Tags: translation, cantonese, food

I am getting married in a month's time and my Chinese-speaking father has invited some of his Chinese friends to my wedding. He is and his friends are elderly and their English is almost non-existent. I spent a week compiling Chinese wedding invitations to make it a little bit more personal and I was really proud of myself. However this next challenge has proven a bit too much for me: TRANSLATING THE MENU!!!! Can anyone help me with translating the menu please? I've put it all together the way that I think I would say it however I don't know how it sounds written down and to make things harder, I need the Cantonese phrases! T_T
Thank you!

Starter
開胃菜*(I'm not entirely convinced this is right, 起頭菜 comes to mind but i might have completely fabricated that!)*

Oxtail in Madeira & horseradish broth & herb dumplings (gluten free without dumplings)
牛尾在馬德拉和辣根湯及圓子(免圓子為没麵筋)

Braised onion tart, Blacksticks blue cheese, pecans & dressed rocket (v)
紅燒洋蔥芝士撻及合桃沙律(齋)

Main Course
主菜

Confit duck leg with mustard mash, green beans & Savoy cabbage, with honey & clove sauce (gluten free) 
煨鴨腿及芥菜mash*(嘛薯??? haha we call it that but is it right?)*，豆仔和savoy cabbage 及蜜糖丁香醬 (没麵筋)

Fillet of sea bass with pommes Anna, spinach and braised leeks with red wine & star anise sauce (gluten free)
鱸魚及安娜／牛油薯仔(?)，菠菜，燉韭蔥及紅酒和八角汁 (没麵筋)

Butternut squash brulee, black olive crumble, spinach & truffled potato dauphinoise (v) 
南瓜布丁，烏欖, 菠菜，松露奶油薯仔 (齋)

Dessert
甜品

Baked lemon cheesecake with ginger & blackcurrant (v) 
焗檸檬芝士蛋糕及薑和黑加侖子(齋)

Chocolate and orange parfait with orange compote & praline crunch (v)
朱古力和橙芭菲及橙果盤和果仁糖(齋)

Fruit salad (v) (gluten free)
水果沙律 (齋)(没麵筋)

Comment: May we know which region your husband is from? The translation may be a bit different.

Comment: My husband to be is British, so unfortunately this burden is mine alone! haha

Answer (score 3):

To translate a menu, you may remember:

- Each one course is a noun or a phrase, avoid sentence or very long phrase;
- Avoid colloquial language, use formal written language.

  - For example: use "無" instead of "沒". use "開胃菜" but not "起頭菜".

Here are some my translations:

Oxtail in Madeira & horseradish broth & herb dumplings (gluten free without dumplings): 馬德拉（馬嗲利 in Cantonese）燴牛尾(or紅燴牛尾)配辣根素丸(除素丸外無谷蛋白)

mustard mash: 芥末薯蓉

Savoy cabbage: 高麗菜

It's likely that your language environment of Chinese is Cantonese, so I applied traditional Chinese as much as possible, but a few usage may not be the same since I speak Mandarin.

Comment: I assume 'mustard mash' refers to mashed potatoes with mustard through them - does `泥` specifically refer to mashed potatoes?

Comment: @Cocowalla Nope, it can be used on other indigents like mashed taro (芉泥). For mashed potatoes in Cantonese I'd suggest to use 薯蓉. (薯泥 is also acceptable but less common)

Comment: @TactMayers that's what I thought - so `芥末泥` would (presumably wrongly) mean `mashed mustard` then?

Comment: @Cocowalla Yes. According to my understanding.

Comment: @TactMayers Thank you so the suggestion "薯蓉", I don't know that before("土豆泥" in my environment).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Congratulations!

---

Starter => 前菜

Oxtail in Madeira & horseradish broth & herb dumplings (gluten free without dumplings) => 馬德拉辣根清湯燴牛尾及香草雲吞 (麵筋/麩質敏感人士可免雲吞)

Braised onion tart, Blacksticks blue cheese, pecans & dressed rocket => 焗洋蔥撻伴藍芝士合桃火箭菜 (素菜)  [I presume that it is one dish with tart, cheese and rocket, right?]

Confit duck leg with mustard mash, green beans & Savoy cabbage, with honey & clove sauce (gluten free) => 油封鴨伴芥末四季豆蓉，配蜂蜜丁香汁 (不含麵筋/麩質) [If the sauce is thick, say 蜂蜜丁香醬]

Fillet of sea bass with pommes Anna, spinach and braised leeks with red wine & star anise sauce (gluten free) => 海鱸魚柳伴牛油焗薄薯片、菠菜及燒韭蔥，配八角紅酒汁 (不含麵筋/麩質)

Butternut squash brulee, black olive crumble, spinach & truffled potato dauphinoise (v) => 南瓜布丁，黑橄欖鬆餅，菠菜，松露奶油焗薯 (素菜) [Hey, do you have a picture of the dish?  I don't have any idea how to translate it.]

Dessert => 甜品

Baked lemon cheesecake with ginger & blackcurrant (v) => 黑加侖子檸檬芝士薑餅 (素菜) [Is ginger in the crust?]

Chocolate and orange parfait with orange compote & praline crunch (v) => 朱古力芭菲伴蜜餞香橙及碎果仁 (素菜) [I presume that the "orange compote" refer to the "orange" in the parfait"]

Fruit salad (v) (gluten free) => 鮮果沙律 (素菜, 不含麵筋/麩質)

Comment: +1 for correct translations (not google translate-translation)

Comment: Henry thank you so much! I realised only after reading your translations that I was literally translating the dishes even though I have actually seen and tasted the dishes> For example your cheesecake observation is correct, the ginger is in the base not separate! This has been very helpful, and has enabled me to make amendments to my translation with confidence! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Alex, Google Translation is getting worse and worse.

Comment: Very nice translations. I am hungry:)